# Double-Slit Experiment /w Switch

Tags: double-slit-experiment, interference

So if you perform the double-slit experiment without detection, you'll see an interference pattern.  If you interfere with a photon at the slit, you'll see the wave-form collapse.

So if you turn the detector switch on and off, as you're observing the pattern, would you observe the waveform collapse/un-collapse in real-time?

Comment: You mean you're only observing *some* of the photons coming through? I suppose you'd just get an overlayed pattern of two lines (made by the photons you observed) on top of an interference pattern (made by the photon's you didn't observe)

Comment: I mean you're literally standing there turning the power to the detector on/off, say every 2 seconds.  Would the pattern simply rotate between interference/non-interference?

Comment: @bperniciaro yes it would simply convert to and fro interference/non-interference pattern. But remember in this case you are not seeing the wave function collapse of the same photon that already passed through. So the term "un-collapse" doesn't make sense. The interference will be due to some different set of photons.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Physics SE! Look around, and take the [tour]. The double (and single) slit experiment causes much confusion with many people, particularly since it is often their first introduction to quantum physics messing with their classical intuition.